# Backbone.js - Knockout-style rendering on collections

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, knockout.js

Both of these frameworks are great, but I've noticed that Knockout likes to point out that it has the ability to render only the newest items that are added to a list - instead of rendering the whole list.  Which, of course, is a performance booster for larger apps.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about (be sure to check the 'show render times' box):  http://knockoutjs.com/examples/collections.html

But, this seems like something that any major javascript framework would have - since it is so important.

**So is this feature also baked into Backbone, and how would I go about implementing it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently ran across this, which does exactly what I was looking for:  https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.modelbinding

Derick Bailey is a VERY proficient JavaScript developer and here is an accompanying article that he wrote about model-binding for Backbone:
http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/24/awesome-model-binding-for-backbone-js/

Hope it's helpful to someone else.

**EDIT**

---

Derick also has a composite framework for Backbone to help reduce boilerplate code:  http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/12/16/composite-javascript-applications-with-backbone-and-backbone-marionette/

Answer (score 1):

The following is a backbone sample that does just that.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html

```
...
    initialize: function() {
      this.input    = this.$("#new-todo");
      Todos.bind('add',   this.addOne, this);
    },


    // Add a single todo item to the list by creating a view for it, and
    // appending its element to the `<ul>`.
    addOne: function(todo) {
      var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
      $("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);
    },
...
```

Comment: Yeah, I've seen how to do it manually before.  From what I can see, Knockout does it automatically when pushing a new element into its observableArray.  I'm mainly trying to find out if there is a way to do the binding automatically.  It's just a few lines of code and not a big deal if you can't - but if there was a plugin or something that made backbone do it automatically, that would be nice.

Comment: You can create a view that automatically binds to the collection add event, then extend it for other views.